# SecureSocial not using extended classes in Play! 2.1 project inside SBT Multi-Project

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.1, securesocial

Currently I have a Play! 2.1 project that is a sub-project of an SBT Multi-Project that is a front-end interface. The Play! project uses SecureSocial for typical authentication.

I will typically first start the SBT console to run my internal services locally in separate terminals. Finally I perform a `play "project interface" "~run 9000"` command in a new window to start up the interface sub-project using Play!. Problem is that on a fresh load (even after a clean) SecureSocial does not use my extended services and providers, and instead falls back on its own.

I will make a source change and reload, where SecureSocial will then use my own classes but suddenly starts throwing `ClassCast` exceptions using two of the same types, indicating there are conflicting ClassLoaders.

Is there a proper way to set this up so this doesn't happen? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Though not a real solution, I have in the meantime developed a workaround where I manually instantiate my own extended `UserService` class and bring the current Application instance into scope. I also wrote my own providers and `SecureAction` wrappers and designed them to use the custom `UserService`. It's a lot of extra code, but works around the problem.